# Hydro-electric gravity problem - Is there a air-resistance-like force affecting water flow down a mountain making placing hydro-electric ?

Tags: gravity, forces, fluid-dynamics, energy, electricity

Say I have a theoretical mountain with a river starting exactly at the peak. Gravity would act on the water, accelerating it down the mountain. There would also be a force limiting the water's velocity. My question is: "Would collecting the energy from the water in intervals, allowing the water to reach its 'terminal velocity' before the next collection point, be more optimal than a single hydro-electric generator at the bottom?

I think it would be, but I am not a physicist or engineer (yet) so there may be something integral I am missing. Here is a picture of a similar situation I am referring to to help understand:

http://www.directionalenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Run-Of-River-1024x593.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The air in an idealized stream (no white-water rapids) would be at the top of the stream, so that the water would flow inhindered.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal velocity is only achieved by object in free fall with air resistance balancing the weight. The main resistance to water flow on a river (at an angle to the surface so that the downward acceleration is much less than $$g$$ of course) is caused due to friction with the mountain surface. Air resistance (i.e. fluid friction/drag) has practically no effect on the water flow. If the water reaches a constant speed it will be because the dynamic friction between the water and mountain surface would have equalled the acceleration down the mountain slope.

Collecting water at different points would slow down the water flow so that the component of the weight of the water down the slope is again greater than the friction between the water and mountain surface causing the water to speed up again and reach a constant velocity. Of course, this is assuming that the slope is of a constant gradient. As far as I can tell, there will be no effect on the efficiency of energy generation with this method.

Comment: Would it be more effective to have several generators spaced out on the mountain, or one at the bottom?

Comment: Depends on the steepness of the mountain. In any case, the most sensible approach would be to position multiple spaced out generators  near the bottom of the mountain. Water rarely stops speeding up in real life while passing down a mountain slope.

Answer (score 0):

Water sliding down a mountain in a stream will hit a terminal velocity when it transitions to turbulent flow, at which point it begins churning up the air nearby and entraining it in the flow. that churning wastes the energy in the flow, reducing the amount available at the bottom of the mountain for power generation.

This effect can be eliminated by flowing the water downhill in a closed pipe. In this case the terminal velocity will be greater than in the open-channel flow case, but fluid friction will still set a speed limit on the falling water, again limiting the extractable power at the bottom of the mountain.

This effect can be reduced by increasing the pipe diameter to reduce the flow velocity in the pipe and thereby reduce pressure losses due to friction. In the limit of a really big pipe we obtain a *reservoir* with water entering it at its open top and squirting out of a small nozzle in the bottom, and using that squirt to spin a turbine.

In practical terms, since power is the product of a flow and an effort variable, that product is maximized when the flow (mass per second) and effort (pressure) are both maximized, which occurs when they are numerically equal (assuming consistent units). This criterion is used to design the pipes leading from the reservoir to the turbine.

Note also that high flow at low pressure can deliver the same power as low flow at high pressure, and that the turbine itself can be designed to make best use of either. High pressure and low flow implies the use of an *impulse turbine*, like a Pelton wheel, while high flow and low pressure dictates the use of an axial flow turbine that looks like an ship's propeller, as used along the course of the Columbia River in the Pacific Northwest.